# Not able to see Test Run History in TFS

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, visualstudio, tfs

We have started **IV&V** of a project and the actual Test team of that project is maintaining Test cases over TFS. That team has already created and executed some part of the test cases. My part is to review Test cases and execution process, but I am facing an issue that 'I am not able to see the execution history of the test cases'.

TFS 2013 (***I tried to see history using VSTS Ultimate, Microsoft Test Manager and TFS Web Explorer***) displays me the status of only 1 execution round, while **I want to see the history of past executed rounds** *(if any)* and what was the status of test cases when they were executed earlier?, this status is required to build a progress report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Microsoft Test Manager, in the Testing Center view, select Test, then Analyze Test Runs.

You'll get the test run history for all runs of your current test plan.

[image: TFS Test Run History]

Comment: This looks a bit complex/lengthy process to me for creating reports, but I think this is TFS provide results. Is there any other similar view which can provide me data like in Iteration1 or 14-Jul-15: 50 Pass, 40 Failed and 10 Not Executed (in tabular or graphical form) and in Iteration2 or 14-Aug-15: 70 Pass, 20 Failed and 10 Not Executed (in tabular or graphical form). Is this possible to achieve such report directly from TFS or Test manager? If TFS doesn't provide such option, than too I am Ok but just want to know.

Comment: I think I got what I need. I investigated the tool (Test manager) a bit more and able to see the graphical version of the different test runs. Thanks for showing the direction :)